# Spring OAuth2 - Authorization Server - Differentiate users on clients

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-oauth2

i'm stuck with my application. It's sound simple: I have two clients registered on my OAuth AuthorizationServer and two users. User *alpha* can access both apps ("androidapp" and "angularapp"), but user *beta* only can access to one of these applications (only "angularapp"). How I can differentiate the users and block beta for the "androidapp" app?

This is my AuthServer's code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired private DataSource dataSource;
    @Autowired private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security
            .tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
            .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()")
            ;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory().withClient("angularapp")
        .secret(passwordEncoder.encode("12345"))
        .scopes("read", "write")
        .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
        .accessTokenValiditySeconds(20000)
        .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(20000)
        .and()
        .withClient("androidapp")
        .secret(passwordEncoder.encode("67890"))
        .scopes("read", "write")
        .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
        .accessTokenValiditySeconds(20000)
        .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(20000);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {

        endpoints
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
            .tokenStore(tokenStore())
            .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter())
            ;

    }

    @Bean
    public JwtTokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter jwt = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        jwt.setSigningKey(JwtConfig.RSA_PRIVATE_KEY);
        jwt.setVerifierKey(JwtConfig.RSA_PUBLIC_KEY);
        return jwt;
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: One option would be to write your own `ClientDetailsService` implementation and, say, add some custom authorization logic to `loadClientByClientId()`.

Comment: that could work, but at that level I don't have the username to know if the user is or not associated with that application...

Comment: You can get the username from the Security Context.

Comment: Yeah! Your idea works, but the other way around. When the `loadClientByClientId` method is executed, the `Principal` object stored in `SecurityContext` doesn't yet exist, but it does when the `loadUserByUsername` method is executed with a slight observation: The `Principal` object at this point contains the `client_id`, not the `username`, resulting in customizing the `UserDetailsService` object instead of `ClientsDetailsService`. Then, with a relational entity (JPA) I joined the `client_id` with the `username` giving the expected result

Comment: Hmm I find it strange that the principal doesn't yet exist when the load client method is invoked. Have you secured the `/oauth/authorize` endpoint?

Comment: Yup.. 
`{"timestamp": "2019-01-09T12:23:33.641-0300","status": 403,"error": "Forbidden","message": "Access Denied","path": "/oauth/authorize" }`
These days I have discovered that Spring is darker and more bizarre than the Illuminati

Comment: If the `/oauth/authorize` endpoint is properly secured you should be getting a 401 status code, not a 403.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution here:

> When the `loadClientByClientId` method is executed, the `Principal` object
>   stored in `SecurityContext` doesn't yet exist, but it does when the
>   `loadUserByUsername` method is executed with a slight observation: The
>   `Principal` object at this point contains the `client_id`, not the
>   `username`, resulting in customizing the `UserDetailsService` object
>   instead of `ClientsDetailsService`. Then, with a relational entity (JPA)
>   I joined the `client_id` with the `username` giving the expected result.

So, the code for `UserDetailsService` implements is:

```
@Service
public class UsuarioService implements IUsuarioService, UserDetailsService{

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UsuarioService.class);

    @Autowired
    private IUsuarioDao usuarioDao;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Usuario usuario = usuarioDao.findByUsername(username);
        if( usuario == null ) {
            logger.error("Login error: Username not found in storage");
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Login error: Username not found in storage");
        }
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = usuario.getRoles().stream().map( role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority( role.getNombre() )).collect(Collectors.toList());

        Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        String applicationID = "";
        if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
            applicationID = ((UserDetails)principal).getUsername();
        } else {
            applicationID = principal.toString();
        }
        logger.info("Application: {} ", applicationID);

        if( applicationID == null || applicationID.isEmpty() ) {
            logger.error("Application ID can't be empty");
            throw new InsufficientAuthenticationException("Application ID can't be empty");
        }

        OAuthClientDetails app = findApplicationByUsername( usuario.getClientes(), applicationID);
        if( app == null ) {
            logger.error("Unauthorized user for application {}", applicationID);
            throw new UnapprovedClientAuthenticationException("Unauthorized user for application " + applicationID);
        }

        return new User(username, usuario.getPassword(), usuario.getEnabled(), true, true, true, authorities);
    }

    private OAuthClientDetails findApplicationByUsername( final List<OAuthClientDetails> list, final String clientID ){
        return list.stream().filter( p -> p.getClientId().equals(clientID) ).findAny().orElse(null); } }
```

And the AuthorizationServer config is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired DataSource dataSource;
    @Autowired @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean") private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security
            .tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()") 
            .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()") 
            ;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {

        endpoints
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
            .tokenStore(tokenStore())
            .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter())
            ;

    }

    @Bean
    public JwtTokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter jwt = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        jwt.setSigningKey(JwtConfig.RSA_PRIVATE_KEY);
        jwt.setVerifierKey(JwtConfig.RSA_PUBLIC_KEY);
        return jwt;
    }

}
```

Very grateful for the help and ideas.

Answer (score 1):

The way I have solved in the past was to create a subclass of `ResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter` and override this method:

```
protected OAuth2Authentication getOAuth2Authentication(ClientDetails client, TokenRequest tokenRequest) {
```

If you copy the original method from the Spring sources, you have at a certain point access to the client_id (`client.getClientId()`) and the user (`userAuth.getPrincipal()`).

If the role of the user does not match with the client, I throw an `InsufficientAuthenticationException` to avoid that the user can log in.

It would be great if Spring Security would have some kind of callback there to avoid having to copy parts of the code to be able to do this. I have opened https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/791 for this.

Comment: Is a very good idea, take my upvote, but I'm trying not to do exactly what you mention. Lately it is quite recurrent for me access Spring classes, copy, and only slightly modify some methods. As you certainly mention, they should have more consideration in the Spring project.